# RDKit Building Error

Tags: python, c++, apache-flex, boost, rdkit

Rdkit (version: 2013_09_1) `make` gives some errors:

> make[2]:  [Code/GraphMol/SLNParse/testSLNParse]
>
> [Code/GraphMol/SLNParse/CMakeFiles/testSLNParse.dir/all] Error 2

Previous Steps (Boost 1.54.0, EIGEN3)

--------------------------------------------------**BOOST**--------------------------------------------------

```
mkdir ~/boost

mkdir ~/boost/boost-home

cd ~/boost/

wget "source to boost"

tar zxvf boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2

cd boost_1_54_0/

./bootstrap.sh --with-python-version=2.7 

./b2 --prefix=/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/boost/boost-home --enable-unicode=ucs4 link=shared install
```

> export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="lustre/home/ic003/amakris/boost/boost-home/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
>
> export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/boost/boost_1_54_0/bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-5.4.0/release/threading-multi/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

---

----------------------------------------------------**RDKIT**--------------------------------------------------

```
mkdir ~/rdkit

cd ~/rdkit/

wget "source to rdkit"

tar xvf RDKit_2013_09_1.tgz
```

> export RDBASE=/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/rdkit/RDKit_2013_09_1
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$RDBASE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>
> export PYTHONPATH=$RDBASE:$PYTHONPATH

In CMakeLists.txt i have add:

```
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH}"/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/boost/boost-home/include")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/boost/boost-home/lib")
SET(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS "/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/boost/boost-home/lib")
```

in order to ensure that the correct version of boost is used (instead of 1.64 that the system has by default).

```
mkdir $RDBASE/build

cd build
```

> cmake /lustre/home/ic003/amakris/rdkit/RDKit_2013_09_1/ > -DBOOST_ROOT=/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/boost/boost-home -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=ON 
>   -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=OFF 
>   -DRDK_BUILD_INCHI_SUPPORT=ON -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=/lustre/home/ic003/amakris/.local/include/eigen3 -DAVALONTOOLS_DIR=$RDBASE/External/AvalonTools/distrib/SourceDistribution
>   -DRDK_BUILD_AVALON_SUPPORT=ON

**cmake results:**

> -- Check if the system is big endian
>
> -- Searching 16 bit integer
>
> -- Looking for sys/types.h
>
> -- Looking for sys/types.h - found
>
> -- Looking for stdint.h
>
> -- Looking for stdint.h - found
>
> -- Looking for stddef.h
>
> -- Looking for stddef.h - found
>
> -- Check size of unsigned short
>
> -- Check size of unsigned short - done
>
> -- Using unsigned short
>
> -- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
>
> -- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so (found version "2.7.5")
>   -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.5")
>
> -- Boost version: 1.54.0
>
> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
>
> --   python
>
> -- Looking for include file pthread.h
>
> -- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
>
> -- Looking for pthread_create
>
> -- Looking for pthread_create - not found
>
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
>
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
>
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
>
> -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
>
> -- Found Threads: TRUE
>
> -- Could NOT find InChI in system locations (missing:  INCHI_LIBRARY INCHI_INCLUDE_DIR)
>
> -- Found InChI software locally
>
> -- Found BISON: /usr/bin/bison
>
> -- Found FLEX: /usr/bin/flex
>
> -- Boost version: 1.54.0
>
> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
>
> --   regex
>
> -- Configuring done
>
> -- Generating done

When i try to make with (`make -j 4`) i get the following error:

../../../lib/libSLNParse.so.1.2013.09.1: undefined reference to `boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > > const&)'
../../../lib/libSLNParse.so.1.2013.09.1: undefined reference to`boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]:  [Code/GraphMol/SLNParse/testSLNParse] Error 1
make[1]:  [Code/GraphMol/SLNParse/CMakeFiles/testSLNParse.dir/all] Error 2

I know that if i add in cmake **-DRDK_BUILD_SLN_SUPPORT=OFF** the build succeeds. But i need SLN SUPPORT so i don't use it.

Is anyone know what is going wrong? (I want these versions of the above packages and also i have not sudo privileges).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots, and especially ones that are so hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, i update it now