# Error MolFromSmiles - RDkit

Tags: python, c++, boost, rdkit

When i run in python:

```
import rdkit

from rdkit import Chem

from rdkit.Chem import AllChem

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('Oc1ccccc1N2C(=O)Nc3cc(ccc23)C(F)(F)F')
```

I get the following error:

> Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
>
> rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.MolFromSmiles(str)
>
> did not match C++ signature:
>
> MolFromSmiles(std::string SMILES, bool sanitize=True,
> boost::python::dict replacements={})

The installation of Boost (1.54) and Rdkit (2013_09_1) can be found in previous question:

[RDKit Building Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46605557/rdkit-building-error).

Is anyone knows what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which platform are you using?

Comment: I run the above on linux

Comment: I would install the latest rdkit, but with boost 1.64 and see if the error persists.

Comment: I did it, and it does not work. Also i have installed other versions of rdkit with the correct version of boost (for this version of rdkit) and the error persists too.

Comment: m facing the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With rdkit 2022.9.4 the code in the question works as intended.

[image]